# RecyclerView displaying Bluetooth devices crashes after awhile (Out of bounds exception: Size 1,Index 1)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bluetooth

My recyclerview displays the list of bluetooth devices that are found nearby, but after awhile it just crashes, possibly during the addition or removal of bluetooth devices. However, I have all the necessary null checks and notification of item inserted/changed, so I am not sure what am I missing out.

SensorLookup class: where the recyclerview is displayed

```
private val scanResults = mutableListOf<ScanResult>()

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    scan_results_recycler_view.apply {
        adapter = scanResultAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                this@SensorLookup,
                RecyclerView.VERTICAL,
                false
        )
        isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
    }

    val animator = scan_results_recycler_view.itemAnimator
    if (animator is SimpleItemAnimator) {
        animator.supportsChangeAnimations = false
    }
}

private val scanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
            val indexQuery = scanResults.indexOfFirst { it.device.address == result.device.address }
            if (indexQuery != -1) { // A scan result already exists with the same address
                scanResults[indexQuery] = result
                scanResultAdapter.notifyItemChanged(indexQuery)
                //scanResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            } else {
                with(result.device) {
                    //Timber.i("Found BLE device! Name: ${name ?: "Unnamed"}, address: $address")
                }
                scanResults.add(result)
                scanResultAdapter.notifyItemInserted(scanResults.size - 1)
                //scanResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            //Timber.e("onScanFailed: code $errorCode")
        }
    }
```

ScanResultAdapter class: Adapter for recyclerView

```
class ScanResultAdapter(
    private val items: List<ScanResult>,
    private val sensorInfoHandler: SensorInfoHandler, //sql database
    private val onClickListener: ((device: ScanResult) -> Unit)
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ScanResultAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = parent.context.layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.row_scan_result,
        parent,
        false
    )


    return ViewHolder(view, sensorInfoHandler, onClickListener)
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.bind(item)
}

class ViewHolder(
    private val view: View,
    private val sensorInfoHandler: SensorInfoHandler,
    private val onClickListener: ((device: ScanResult) -> Unit)
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun bind(result: ScanResult) {
        val deviceName: String = result.device.name ?: "Unnamed"

        if(!result.device.name.isNullOrBlank() || !result.device.name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val result = result.device.name.split("_")
            if (!result.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                val cursor: Cursor = sensorInfoHandler.getById(result[1].trim()) //error occurs here
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val friendlyname = sensorInfoHandler.getFriendlyName(cursor)
                    val friendlyname2 = sensorInfoHandler.getFriendlyName2(cursor)
                    if ((friendlyname.isNullOrEmpty() || friendlyname.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname == "-" || friendlyname == "null") && (!friendlyname2.isNullOrEmpty() || !friendlyname2.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname2 != "-" || friendlyname2 != null)) {
                       //codes
                    } else if ((friendlyname2.isNullOrEmpty() || friendlyname2.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname2 == "-" || friendlyname2 == null) && (!friendlyname.isNullOrEmpty() || !friendlyname.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname != "-" || friendlyname != "null")) {
                        //codes
                    } else if (!friendlyname.isNullOrEmpty() || !friendlyname.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname != "-" || friendlyname != "null" || !friendlyname2.isNullOrEmpty() || !friendlyname2.isNullOrBlank() || friendlyname2 != "-" || friendlyname2 != null) {
                        //codes
                    }
                } else {
                    //codes
                }
            }
        }}}
```

After awhile of displaying all the bluetooth devices uneventfully, it will just suddenly crash. My suspicions lie on the fact that it because Bluetooth connections are not always stable, hence it can appear and disappear even before the recyclerview has the time to update its dataset. notifydatasetChanged does not seem to work unfortunately, it still crashes and Im not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: which line the crash happens?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look. Ive already added a comment next to the line in the ScanResultAdapter class. //error occurs here

Comment: It happens at:
val cursor: Cursor = sensorInfoHandler.getById(result[1].trim())